# Cows and Bulls game

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean

I'm working on a cows and bulls game with two different classes: 
The first class looks like this: 
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class CowsAndBulls  {

    int UserNumber=0; 
    int CompNumber=0;
    int bulls=0; 
    int cows=0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

    public void getUserNumber() { 
    System.out.println("Please enter your guess!");
    int UserValue=input.nextInt();
    UserNumber=UserNumber+ UserValue;
    System.out.println("Your guess is  : " + UserNumber);
    } 



    public void getCompNumber() { 
        Random generator= new Random();
        int pickedNumber=generator.nextInt(10000) + 1000;
        CompNumber =CompNumber+ pickedNumber;
        System.out.println("The computer has guessed : " + CompNumber );
    }   
}
```

It just generates a random number for the computer and asks the user to input their guess. 
I'm having a lot of trouble with my play class, specifically, I can't get my while loop to run,

```
public class CowsAndBullsPlay {

    public void play() {

    int GuessCount=0; 
    int UserNumber = 0;
    int CompNumber = 0;
    int cows = 0; 
    int bullcount=0;
    int cowcount=0;
    int bulls = 0; 
    Boolean GameEnds; 
    GameEnds=false;

        while (GameEnds=false) { 
            CowsAndBulls user= new CowsAndBulls(); 
            user.getUserNumber(); 
            CowsAndBulls comp= new CowsAndBulls(); 
            comp.getCompNumber();

            String UserString=String.valueOf(UserNumber); 
            String CompString=String.valueOf(CompNumber);
            String U=UserString;
            String C=CompString;
            for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
            for (int k=i+1; k<4; k++) {
                    if(U.charAt(i)==C.charAt(k)) {
                        bullcount ++; 
                        bulls=bulls + bullcount;
                    }   



                else if(U.contains(C.charAt(i) + U)) {      
            //for (int v=0; v<4; v++)
            //for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
                        cowcount ++; 
                        cows=cows + cowcount;
                    }
                    GuessCount++;
            }   
            if (bulls==4) { 
                GameEnds= true; 
                System.out.println("Congratulations!");
                System.out.println("it took you:" + GuessCount);
            } 
            else { 
                System.out.println("cows: " + cows); 
                System.out.println("Bulls:" + bulls);
            }   

        } 
    }
}
```

It's supposed to check for cows and then check for bulls, then if bulls is not equal to four, the loop should reiterate--calling the first two methods that ask for user input and ask computer to randomly generate a number and then guesscount should keep track of loop iterations.

The code compiles, but it just won't run the while loop

here is my tester class:

```
public class CowsAndBullsTester { 

public static void  main(String[] args) {

    int bears = 0;
    int cows = 0;
    Boolean GameEnds = false;

     System.out.println("welcome to Cows Versus Bulls death match!");
     CowsAndBulls user= new CowsAndBulls (); 
     user.getUserNumber(); 

     System.out.println("Now the computer will pick a number!");
     CowsAndBulls comp= new CowsAndBulls (); 
     comp.getCompNumber(); 

     System.out.println("Let's see how you did!");
     CowsAndBullsPlay game= new CowsAndBullsPlay();
     game.play(); 
    }
}
```

Really appreciate any help. I'm sure there's some stupid mistake, I'm just not sure what. This is only my third assignment and I'm having some trouble figuring out what's wrong on my own :)

thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You need to change `while (GameEnds=false)` to `while (GameEnds==false)`.

The first is an assignment, while the second is a comparison.  So in the first, `false` will be assigned to `GameEnds`, and then `GameEnds` will evaluate to `false` for your `while` condition, meaning that the loop will never enter.

Also, see @AndrewMao's comment below.  Generally, you will see `boolean`s used in conditions directly, with or without negation (`!`), because they already hold truth values and a further comparison is redundant.

---

*Small side note: you may want to rename your variable in `camelCase` for clarity.*

Comment: Better yet, just `while(!GameEnds)`

Comment: thank you!! The while loop is running now, but I'm having a string index out of bounds exception with this line:                     if(U.charAt(i)==C.charAt(k)) in the game class. any for why this is going wrong? There must be a problem with the index, but I can't see what